# If I approximate a Bionimial distribution with a Normal Distribution am I still allowed to use Binomial's equation for Variance?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

If I approximate a Binomial distribution with a Normal Distribution am I still allowed to use Binomial 's equation for Variance?

So am I still allowed to use this:

$Var(x) = np(1 − p)$

While still using this Tolerance Interval of a normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, we use the mean and variance of the binomial.

Comment: Can I use this one even if I didn't use a binomial to get my normal distribution? Can I use this shortcut all the time? In other words when do I have to use this in a normal distribution :

$Var(X) = E[(X-μ)^{2}]$

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. If $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are independent identically distributed random variables, each with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and if $n$ is "large" then $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ has close to normal distribution, mean $n\mu$ variance $n\sigma^2$.

Comment: I mean when can you use this: $Var(x) = np(1 − p)$ and when do you have to use this -> http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/e/8/7e8361a32aa7ca2349ed71171c45bc26.png